# Designer 2010 workflow failed on start with error RunWorkflow: System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

We migrated our SharePoint Site from SP 2010 to SP 2013. We have a designer workflow on a custom list and the workflow has couple of approval task forms. The issue we are facing is, workflow 'Failed on start' only for the first item added on day. Workflows works fine and assigns task forms as expected from the second item. I checked the ULS logs and I see these messages-

> RunWorkflow: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
> 'C:\Users\accountname\AppData\Local\Temp\c1e6ac0b-c897-4e0c-bb6d-a6bae5c4f572\Xoml.c198ca3c_a20b_4eef_b7f0_de437f582651.16.3072.18.3072.dll'
> is denied
> The name of the dll changes with every day.

Workflow history show -

> Workflow Cancelled === System Account ===Workflow XXX was canceled by System
> Account.
>
> Error     ===         System Account === XXX failed to
> start.

Comment: I assume you've republished the workflow using SPD 2013 in the new environment?

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can check:

1. Open SharePoint Designer 2013 using an Administrator account, which is **not** System Account, then publish the workflow again.
2. Clear the SharePoint Designer cache. Reference: [How to Clear Your SharePoint Designer 2010/2013 Cache.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33469.how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache.aspx)
3. Clear the SharePoint Designer login credentials as referred in this post: [SharePoint designer 2013 workflow saving error.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-saving-error/d0ab325b-314f-42b5-956d-822f717e995a)